# What's wrong in creating/using a shared library with gcc here?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

In `libname.h`:

```
int add_libname(int, int);
```

In `libname.c`:

```
#include "libname.h"

int add_libname(int a, int b)
{
  return a+b;
}
```

I can build the shared library this way:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC libname.c -o libname.so
```

But I can't use it in another programe `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libname.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  printf("%d\n", add_libname(1,5));
}
```

Reporting `undefined reference to add_libname` when I try to build it..

What's wrong here?

Comment: How are you compiling test.c?

Comment: @Chris I was thinking that too but it looks like theres a typo in the call to add_libname

Comment: @Jesus - That typo would not produce the error the OP is asking about. It should produce an error, but a compile-time one, not a link-time one.

Comment: @Chris Lutz ,`gcc -Wall test.c -o test`.I also tried append `-llibname`,doesn't work either...

Comment: @new_perl check the 2nd half of my answer

Comment: new_perl,It says undefined reference becuase you did not mention the .h file and .so file pathe linker searches in its default lib directory.But you have to mention the .h path and the .so path whenever you create a new .so library.

Comment: @niko he has the header included using quotes so it should be in the immediate directory

Comment: Ok but specifying the total path in the gcc command line is more safe.and he/she must include the library path also to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because add_libname takes (int, int) you're giving it (1+5 = 6) or just (int)

I think you meant
    add_libname(1, 5);

Also to compile it correctly you must use gcc like so

```
gcc -o myapp test.c -L. -lname
```

the lib part of libname is ignored as it is implicit

Comment: This is certainly an error, but I doubt it is the error the OP is asking about. It's an error (s)he _should_ be noticing if his/her compiler warnings were high enough (and if (s)he copied/pasted actual code instead of rewriting it from memory to SO.)

Comment: @Chris Yeah it's just that they're not specifying how they compiled the other file. I'm just going on what I can see at this point I'll edit in the gcc line he needs to compile it correctly.

Comment: @new_perl, ignore the first half of the answer and just use the correct gcc line.

Comment: For C++, this would create a link error; nice catch.  But it is not likely to create this a error for C, which does not perform name mangling.  (It is likely to fail at run time, of course.)

Comment: @Nemo that is correct upon execution it would warn that a dependency could not be fulfilled (which would be the libname library)

Comment: @Jesus:  No, it would not; that is my point.  It would simply call the function with garbage as the second argument.  Unlike C++, C function symbols do not encode argument types in their names...  So when you try to call a C function incorrectly, it calls the function with garbage arguments.  (In short, the error mentioned by the user could not be caused by the wrong arguments being passed.)  If you do not believe me, try it.

Comment: @Nemo the case I mentioned was when you dynamically link the library but fail to find the library. The executable will link correctly but when run it will fail because it cannot find it. We were referring to different scenarios :\ such as a case where you move the executable without the library that it links against.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos,it seems if won't fail if there's unresolved symbols when building shared library,but will fail when building an executable, is that the case?

Comment: @new_per It won't fail when COMPILING because during compilation stages the compiler reserves locations for those function calls (because they could be in a library that hasn't been linked yet) during the LINKING stage is it would error out because it can't fill in that placeholder because it doesn't know where the function is

Comment: @Jesus Ramos,my question is why no error is reported at the linking stage of building a shared library when it can't fill in that placeholder?

Comment: @new_perl, the library is building fine. You're getting the error when trying to link all the files together because -o calls the linker in order to resolve all external references.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos,but the fact is the `-o` call doesn't report any error when its output is a library even if it fails to resolve all references.

Comment: because when you build a library you create an object file you don't link to an executable.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos,are you sure about this? AFAIK,`.so` is of the same format of an executable: `ELF`.

Comment: @new_perl from what I know a library exports an address table in most cases which only requires compilation, your program links to that library to make use of that address table to fill in and resolve the symbols that were referenced in your executable that makes use of that library

Answer (score 1):

To create a shared library use these

```
   gcc -fPIC -c libname.c 
   it gives warning: position independent code and libname.o file is generated.
```

and now type these command,

```
    gcc -shared libname.so libname.o
```

libname.so ( the shared library is created with .so extension). To use the shared library

```
gcc -I/give the path of libname.h  sourcefile.c  /give the path of your .so file
```

example if your c file is file.c and the header file libname.h is in c:\folder1\project and your libname.so (shared library) is in c:\folder\project2
then

```
gcc -I/cygdrive/c/folder1/project file.c /cygdrive/c/folder/project/libname.so
```

this is the gcc command to be used while using the shared library.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't compile `libname.so` in one GO?

Comment: To be honest i never tried.I dont know whether it works or not.But did my answer solve your problem? Did u understand how to use a shared library ?

Comment: Gave you 1 upvote because its usually problem faced by everyone when they start using the shared libraries but I suggest you to refer the previous questions also on stackoverflow

Comment: can you explain the diff b/w `-lname` and embed `libname.so` directly?

Comment: @new_perl. Jesus gave you the wrong code up above there, the command he gave works only for static libraries but not for the shared libraries. -lname is indicated for the static libraries whereas libname.so is for shared libraries.You got the point?

Comment: @new_perl did you understand the difference and how to use a shared library, If you have any more doubts then let me clarify it to u and never forget to accept an answer.I have been trying from days but never i got an upvote or acceptance to my answer )) but i still keep trying on.

Comment: you know the difference between static library and shared library . dont you?

Comment: `-lname` does not only work for static libraries. It actually uses a static library only if it can't find a dynamic library (or if you override it to use static libraries by default).